# Spring Batch: completed job is not actually ending

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using Spring Batch 3.0.1.
I have a two-steps job.

- First step is a read-process-write chunk. It generates PDF files with iText,and writes in two databases with Atomikos and JTA.
- Second one is only a dummy step to log in the file "*process ended*"

I have configured it, launched it with *CommandLineJobRunner* way, and the work I expected has been done, both PDFs and databases.

The final message "*process ended*" is written; and, in *batch_job_execution* and *batch_step_execution* database tables, the rows are written with *COMPLETED* status and exit code, and end time is fulfilled.

So, my problem is that prompt is not coming back, and the process seems to be executing.
When I debug the process with Eclipse, the behaviour is the same: work is done, but the process does not end. Threads related to Atomikos, database pool and step remain as running, and I don't understand why.

The test case has 9 PDFs (items) to process.
The first step configuration is this:

```
<bean id="printingTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize"   value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize"    value="20" />
    <property name="queueCapacity"  value="50" />

    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<step id="pdfStep" next="endLoggerStep">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" task-executor="printingTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="10" >
            <batch:chunk reader="pdfItemReader" processor="pdfItemProcessor" writer="pdfItemWriter" commit-interval="20">
            </batch:chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

*pdfItemReader* is a JdbcPagingItemReader with *pageSize* parameter with 20 value too.

How can I actually finalize the process in command line or Eclipse? Any wrong configuration?
Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

[SOLVED]
I was going mad with this. Finally, when logging with trace level, the last line was:

*Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'atomikosTransactionManager'*

I changed the flag *forceShutdown* to true, and finally the program ends gratefully.

```
<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="true" /><!-- Change this to true -->
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That happens once in a test I did, the problem was the processor that I forget to do it correctly and enter in an endless loop, please paste your code for processor and reader as well the writer, that will be a misunderstood of concept too.

Comment: @Koitoer , finally I solve the trick. I don't know why, but Atomikos transaction manager did not end right. I force it to end with a parameter (I explain it in the question edition). Thanks.

Comment: Curious, I've seen this behavior before when including ehcache & spring cache in a spring batch job.  The ehcache cache manager wouldn't shutdown even after the batch job quit.  I wonder if it has a similar force shutdown option...

Comment: @icebox13, I'm sorry but I haven't integrated ehcache with Spring. What did it happen finally? Did you solve it? Let us know. Thanks.

Comment: @yaki_nuka No, I didn't really solve it. For one batch application that uses ehcache, I'm doing the spring-batch configuration in XML.  I don't have the issue there.  For the other batch application, I kept the annotation configuration and just took out ehcache, and wrote a quick a couple of quick & dirty cache classes to meet my needs.

Comment: I am using bean configuration. How should I implement this?
@Bean(name = "resourcelessTransactionManager")
 public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
  ResourcelessTransactionManager rltm = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
  return rltm;
 }

Answer (score -3):

You can use System.exit(0); at the end of your main class which will terminate JVM eventually terminating the batch execution.

Comment: Maybe, it's a great disruptive effect to force a System.exit(0) in a Spring scenario. But, thank you for your comment.